# Product of relations described in categorical terms?

Tags: category-theory, relations

Can cartesian product of several (not necessarily binary) relations be described in categorical terms?

Don't propose me direct product in the category **Set**, as it does not preserve the structure of relations.

Comment: You know there's a category $\textbf{Rel}$, right?

Comment: @Zhen Lin: <strong>Rel</strong> is for binary relations but my relations are of arbitrary arity.